# Faster way to load .csv files in folder and display them using imshow in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, csv

I have a piece of MATLAB code that works fine, but I wanted to know is there any faster way of performing the same task, where each .csv file is a 768*768 dimension matrix

Current code:

```
for k = 1:143
    matFileName = sprintf('ang_thresholded%d.csv', k);
    matData = load(matFileName);
    imshow(matData)
end
```

Any help in this regard will be very helpful. Thank You!

Comment: Are you displaying 143 images?!?!

Comment: Yes, frame gets updated with every increment in the loop.

Comment: I will be adding more lines of code in the 'for' loop for processing these images along with displaying histogram and I feel that it will make it further slow, so want to come up a faster alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another option using [Matlab's data stores](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/datastore.html) which are designed to work with large datasets or lots of smaller sets.  The [TabularTextDatastore](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tabulartextdatastore.html) is specifically for this kind of text based data.

Something like the following.  However, note that since I don't have any test files it is sort of notional example ...

```
ttds = tabularTextDatastore('.\yourDirPath\*.csv'); %Create the data store

while ttds.hasdata %This turns false after reading the last file.
    temp = read(ttds); %Returns a Matlab table class
    imshow(temp.Variables)
end
```

Since it looks like your filenames' numbering is not zero padded (e.g. 1 instead of 001) then the file order might get messed up so that may need addressed as well.  Anyway I thought this might be a good alternative approach worth considering depending on what else you want to do with the data and how much of it there might be.

Answer (score 1):

In general, its better to separate the loading, computational and graphical stuff. 
If you have enough memory, you should try to change your code to:

```
n_files=143;
% If you know the size of your images a priori:
matData=zeros( 768, 768,n_files); % prealocate for speed.
for k = 1:n_files
      matFileName = sprintf('ang_thresholded%d.csv', k);
      matData(:,:,k) = load(matFileName);
end

seconds=0.01;
for k=1:n_Files
   %clf; %Not needed in your case, but needed if you want to plot more than one thing (hold on)
   imshow(matData(:,:,k));
   pause(seconds); % control "framerate"
end
```

Note the use of `pause()`.

Comment: That's a great tip, it takes lot of time in loading the files in matData

Comment: @Ander - what about preallocation? :O

Comment: @Dev-iL..Can you please throw some more light of "preallocation"?

Comment: @Laveena https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html

Comment: If you use `for k = n_files:-1:1` then you don't need the pre-allocation, the first assignment will do it for you (although your data will be stored in the reversed order of course).

Comment: You can also load them into a cell array. This has two advantages: (1) no indexed assignment into numeric array, indexing sometime seems to be the slowest aspect of MATLAB; and (2) will work if not all images are of the same size.

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, I though about cell arrays, but often matrices are way faster to operate with, especially if image processing stuff is going to happen. I generally avoid using cells unless I have to